# Realistic cocoa cream!

Tags: particles, shaders, weight-painting

Hey guys I hope you can help me out, I am struggling on a cream.
Right now I am doing it with particle but I don't like the result, maybe you have an idea. And maybe u have also an Idea for the marshmallow shader.
Would be nice, already thank you.
[image]

Comment: there is a well respected video tutorial by Mr Sorbias covering bubbles in coffee https://youtu.be/4rNrL7a12xg . The marshmallows looks right for when they have been in the liquid for a while.

Comment: That was my reference but how u can see it isnt realistic enough

Comment: The bubbles do look a bit clay-like. I would try and make them more glossy and play with the transparency. The flat bubbles look great, it's just where they are piling up against the marshmallows that they look a bit false and that is only in the left hand image.